# Auto named-anchors in markdown

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I am using Markdown in PHP and have written a regex to automatically wrap the text inside if any `<h1>-<h6>` tag with a named-anchor (`<a name="Text">Text</a>`) for linking.

Here is the PHP:

```
$text = '<p>This is a</p>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <p>to see if this works </p>';

$regex = '/\<h([0-6]{1})\>(.+)\<\/h[0-6]{1}\>/';

echo preg_replace($regex, '<h$1><a name="$2">$2</a></h$1>', $text);
```

And the result is:

```
<p>This is a</p>
<h1><a name="Test">Test</a></h1>
<p>to see if this works </p>
```

The important thing here is, Markdown is light-weight and easy on storage space. Manually adding in the named-anchors kind of defeats the purpose of using Markdown altogether.

This method works fine for testing purposes, but I would like to know (and here is the question) if there is a better, more ***language-agnostic***, way to accomplish this.

**NOTE:** The client this is for, wants it this way because they feel even the native Markdown syntax may alienate their more "computer-illiterate" users: `# [Text](#Text)`. They simply want to type: `# Text`

Comment: Why not modify Markdown? It's cleaner, more robust, and probably simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as you're already using PHP, you should really take a look at the [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#header-id) implementation. From the MDE docs:

> With PHP Markdown Extra, you can set id attribute to headers. You should add the id prefixed by a hash inside curly brackets after the
>   header at the end of the line, like this:
>
> ```
> Header 1            {#header1}
> ========
>
> ## Header 2 ##      {#header2}
> ```
>
> Then you can create links to different parts of the same document like this:
>
> ```
> [Link back to header 1](#header1)
> ```